# Is it incorrect to use 'There is ~' in reference to a single proper noun?

Tags: grammaticality, proper-nouns, existentials

Is #1 wrong?

> 1. There is Mt. Everest on the border between China and Nepal.

and should it be #2,

> 2. Mt. Everest is on the border between China and Nepal.

Comment: Note that #1 could also possibly be an existential construction which could be valid in some contexts. For example, A: *"Are there any mountains in Asia that have three #E's in its name, and where would they be located?"* B: *"There is Mt. Everest on the border between China and Nepal."* -- EDIT: Dang it. I see that @StoneyB had already made a similar comment earlier! (I must have a really slow network or something.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what you are trying to say.

> **Mt. Everest** is on the border between China and Nepal.

as a statement of fact on the location of Mt. Everest is fine.

But let's say we are in an airplane flying nearby. I point out the window and say:

> **There is Mt. Everest,** on the border between China and Nepal.

(Comma optional, usually should be there but if you were already talking about the border specifically, maybe not:

> (Flying from from Nepal to China) There is Mt. Everest on the border between China and Nepal.

Comment: The existential construction also works if you're declaring Mt Everest to be a hitherto-unmentioned member of a previously defined set: ***A:** Are there any mountains whose peaks straddle national borders? **B:** Well, there's Mt. Everest on the border between China and Nepal.*

Comment: Might just be a style difference, but I would say that "There is Mt. Everest on the border between China and Nepal." needs a comma.  Not 100% sure of the grammatical justification for it.  I don't think @StoneyB 's construction needs a comma, just to clarify.

Comment: I agree on the comma statement... I would generally write that with a comma, too.